# Remapping a MIDI keyboard controller

Tags: midi, max-msp, programming

I'm a total beginner. For my musical harmony research I would like to remap my MIDI keyboard so that the notes follow the order I choose and not the default sequence by increasing pitch. That is, I wish, for example, to press a key and hear the note I choose, not the one normally assigned to the key. I would like to remap all 88 keys grouping them by "harmonic centers", so I need a patch that substitutes the usual key to note assignment list and instead follows my assignment list. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using MAX/MSP?

Answer (score 1):

You basically need a software with numerical processing of MIDI input. It's like the next thing to writing a driver, but some software offers very direct manipulation of MIDI input:

MIDIOX, Pd, Logic, Max (mentioned in the comments). You could achieve it with Ableton Live as well, although you would have to jump through some hoops.